# Updating multiple charts in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote a simple VBA macro to update the data range for over 50 charts on one worksheet
It can also update the data worksheet if I copy the charts to another another worksheet
The data range update works but when I also try to change the datasheet I get application-defined or object-defined error.

Thanks for your help
Ilan GV

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+J
'
Dim SF As String
Dim grph As ChartObject
Dim ser As Series

'Loop Through Each chart in the ActiveSheet
  For Each grph In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
    For Each ser In grph.Chart.SeriesCollection
            'Get series Formula
            SF = ser.Formula
            'Change the range of both X and Y data
            SF = Replace(SF, "$170", "$171")
            'Change data sheet
            SF = Replace(SF, "Sheet1!", "Sheet2!")
            ser.Formula = SF
    Next
    'Adjust X axis
    grph.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale = grph.Chart.Axes(xlCategory).MaximumScale + 1
  Next
End Sub
```